# I keep getting the problem if biNumber[i] == "1": TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why?

Tags: python

This is my full code:

```py
def bin2dec(biNumber):
    deCnumber = 0
    step = 128
    for i in range(0, 8):
        if biNumber[i] == "1":
            deCnumber += step
        step = step / 2
    return(deCnumber)

number = int(input("Enter a binnumber"))
answer = bin2dec(number)
print(number)
```

Comment: Can you use `int(input("..."), base=2)`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The error tells you that `biNumber[i]` is meaningless, as you can't index into an integer. As an aside, guidelines for naming variables in python are to use snake case, e.g. `biNumber -> bi_number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert your number to a string in order to slice it. Try it like this:

```
def bin2dec(biNumber):
    deCnumber=0
    step = 128
    biNumber_str = str (biNumber)
    for i in range (len (biNumber_str)):
        if biNumber_str[i] == "1":
            deCnumber += step
            step = step/2
    return(deCnumber)

number = int(input("Enter a binnumber"))
answer = bin2dec(number)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your function better by making it agnostic about the length of the binary number you are converting.

Also, since your function expects a string as argument, you don't need to cast input as `int()`.

Something like this:

```py
def bin2dec(b):
    d = 0
    step = 2 ** (len(b) - 1)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] == "1":
            d += step
        step = step // 2
    return(d)


b = input("Enter a binary number").strip()
print(bin2dec(b))
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
>>> def bin2dec(b):
...     d = 0
...     step = 2 ** (len(b) - 1)
...     for i in range(len(b)):
...         if b[i] == "1":
...             d += step
...         step = step // 2
...     return d
... 
>>> bin2dec('11111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000001')
4611686018423193601
>>> bin2dec('1')
1
>>> bin2dec('0')
0
>>> bin2dec('11')
3
>>>
```

There more points where it can be improved, like validate input to see if it is composed of `zeros` and `ones` only, for example. But I will leave that for you to figure it out.

Finally, here is an alternative implementation using successive powers of 2 instead of divisions:

```py
def bin2dec(b):
    d = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(b[::-1]):
        d += int(n) * 2 ** i
    return d
```

And a more *Pythonic* approach:

```py
def bin2dec(b):
    return sum((int(n) * 2 ** i for i, n in enumerate(b[::-1])))
```